# Using ItemsControl to bind buttons top/left position on canvas Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8, itemscontrol

I am using ItemsControl and have several buttons and place them at a specific location on the canvas. However, the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` always place all buttons at `0,0`.

```
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Width="{Binding Side}" 
                               Height="{Binding Side}" 
                               Background="{Binding BgColor}"              
                               Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}" />         
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Won't it better to use `Margin`?

Comment: In general this should work. Check your bindings are okay (i.e. you don't have any bindings errors in Output window during debugging). Another way is to try and use `Grid` instead of `Canvas` for `ItemsPanelTemplate`, binding `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` to the required values.

Comment: I need to use Canvas because I need to place those buttons or graphical elements randomly on the page that does not contain columns/rows

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I've found for this is to use a RenderTransform in your datatemplate

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
<Canvas />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Button Width="{Binding Side}" Height="{Binding Side}" Background="{Binding BgColor}">
<Button.RenderTransform>
<TranslateTransform X={Binding Left} Y ={Binding Top}/>
</Button.RenderTransform>              
</Button>      
</DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```